# How can I open a georeferenced JPG file in OCAD?

Tags: file-formats, georeferencing, ocad

I have a georeferenced `.jpg` file with the `.jgw` file containing the coordinates. I want to use it as a background in OCAD. But when I open the file as a background, the jpg file is not georeferenced to any coordinates. How can I open it and reference it to the right coordinates in OCAD?

I have done the same thing with a georeferenced `.tif` and a `.tfw` file containing the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Map>Scale and Coordinates System>Real World Coordinates

Video (Flash)

http://www.ocad.com/howtos/113_georeference_a_map_ocad10.htm

Comment: Yes, doing it manually like that is the worst case solution. I would prefer if it would be possible to do automatically as with a georeferenced `.tif`