# Georeference Raster File with WorldFile into an aerial photo using GDAL

Tags: raster, gdal, georeferencing, gdalwarp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I transform a georeferenced JPG to a georeferenced TIF?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2312/how-can-i-transform-a-georeferenced-jpg-to-a-georeferenced-tif)

UPDATE:**Corrected link**

I must note that I am new to GIS so pleas be understanding.

PROBLEM:

I have a raster file in this case it is an ortomap:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/703/ortofoto1.jpg/

and it has JGW (World File)

```
0.683772574816354
0.000000000000000
0.000000000000000
-0.683739485024190
395057.114562241190000
741149.458682749890000
```

Now I want to use GDAL to apply the jpg+jgw to this aerial image:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/688/aerialphoto.jpg/

so that it can have the coordinates according to the jgw file of the jpg ortomap.

**What gdal console commands should I commit on those 3 files and what parameters should I consider?**
(I was thinking gdal_translate/gdalwarp maybe)

Comment: Please create a separate question for your second question> `**2. Can i later use those two jpg files to create a 6 band IMG file with the jgw originated coordinates?**`

Comment: Not duplicate. I am after the jpg+wf and applying its coordinates to the aerial photo. **No** geoTiff here and no WorldFile generation it **already exists** in my case.
What option makes GDAL know about EXISTING jgw file anyway?

Comment: Aren't the two images the same?

Comment: Thank you very much I put the wrong link for the second image. Now it is correct. First  one is ortiomap with worldFile. The second is normal raster. I want the second one to have the coordinates according to the worldFile from the first one.

Comment: In linked topic there is no way to point the gdal to use the coordinates basing on WorldFile given.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no support for georeferencing information or metadata for JPEG files. That's why it needs an external world file. I would suggest that you first [convert it to a georeferenced tiff](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2312/how-can-i-transform-a-georeferenced-jpg-to-a-georeferenced-tif). Once you've done that, you'll then need to do an [image to image georeferencing in QGIS](http://www.netpalantir.it/news/index/how-to-georeference-an-image) or some other GIS package.